# How can I send my bot's response in Embed in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I know how to send embeds in discord.py but I am a little bit confused about this code
Please, anyone, help me with a sample of code for this command.

```py
@client.command()
    async def wanted(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
      if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
    
      wanted = Image.open("wanted.jpg")
    
      asset = user.avatar_url_as(size = 128)
      data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
      pfp = Image.open(data) 
    
      pfp = pfp.resize((257, 257))
    
      wanted.paste(pfp, (99, 201))
      wanted.save("profile.jpg")
      await ctx.send(file = discord.File("profile.jpg"))
```

Comment: You mean, you want to send the image in the embed, right?

Comment: Yes @ŁukaszKwieciński

Answer (score 0):

To send a local image in an embed:

```py
file = discord.File("some_file_path", filename="image.png")
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png") # Same name as in the file constructor

await ctx.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

To add the pfp of the invoker to an embed

```py
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I am doing image manipulation using Pillow, so one of my files is local and the second one would be the user's profile picture.

Comment: Maybe he wants to know how to get a user's profile pic? `author.avatar_url`.

Comment: Yes, how to get the user's pfp